# How to reply to a comment through services in Drupal 7?

Tags: services

I am using Drupal 7 as back-end for a mobile application. I am using comments in my application.

Can anyone help me to reply to comment through web-service?

Comment: did you try posting comment on https://example.com/rest/comment/[comment-id]

Comment: Yes. But it creates a new comment. Not a reply to a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I was able to reply to a comment through web-service.

```
 URL:- example.com/rest/comment
 Method : POST
 Parameters:-
 nid :6
 pid: 4
 comment_body[und][0][value]: Some text
```

Comment: I was doing it using "cid", didn't get my eye on "pid" .. was really helpful though :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this answer just in-case someone finds it useful.

**nid = node id**

**pid = comment id you want to reply to**

```
POST http://example.com/rest/comment


Content-Type: application/json
{
  "nid":28,
  "pid":1,
  "subject":"Comment submitted via JSON REST",
  "comment_body":{
    "und":[
      {
        "value":"This is a great article."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

--Response--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
    <cid>8</cid>
    <uri>http://example.com/api/comment/8</uri>
</result>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope you are using Services Module 3.x. So you can have a look at the unit test case file 
http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/tests/functional/ServicesResourceCommentTests.test?id=refs/heads;id2=7.x-3.x#l100
There have a look at the method testCommentCreate.

```
public function testCommentCreate()
```

This may solve your problem.

Comment: yes. Iam using the very same module. And Iam able to create comments as well through services. But Iam not able to reply to a comment.

Comment: Well, I haven't done that in Services module to reply to a comment but I can see from your previous replies, the replies are becoming as new comment. I think you are missing the
'pid' field here. This is the comment parent id.
$comment->pid = 0; // parent comment id, 0 if none

Comment: I tried with pid as well. But still new comments are being created.

Comment: Then its hard to say. You can post the codes if you want. Also, just to clarify, you used comment_reply function right?
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.pages.inc/function/comment_reply/7

Comment: I have not written any code for this. I was able to save the comments through the url :  example.com/rest/comment

Comment: Just to try, create a custom service and mention the endpoint, then create your own function to save the reply.

Comment: Got it. You just have to pass pid as a parameter. Unfortunately I didn't get it earlier.